# jquery validator is not working with rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-validate

My code is here

```
<%= form_for @subscription, :html => {:id => "gift-card-payment-form"}, :as => :subscription_config, :url => activate_gift_card_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :plan_type, :id => "account_type" %>
    <div id="payement-form-fields-gift">
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :addr1, "BILLING ADDRESS"%>
        <%= f.text_field :addr1, {:placeholder => "Enter Street Address", :class => "input_text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all", :required => "true"}%>
        <span class="error-message-left">
          <%= @subscription.andand.errors[:addr1].andand.first %>
        </span>
      </div>
<%= f.submit "SUBMIT & START READING", :class => "btn btn-gray top10", :id => "payment-submit", :disabled => "true" %>
<% end %>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#gift-card-payment-form").validate({
      rules: {        
        "subscription_config[addr1]": {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {        
        "subscription_config[addr1]" : {
          required: "This field is required"
        }
      }
      // ,
      // submitHandler: function(form) {
      //   $('#payment-submit').attr("disabled", false);
      //   $('#payment-submit').addClass('active');
      // }
    });
});
</script>
```

This working sometimes but it is not working properly please help me.

Comment: ***"working sometimes but it is not working properly"* is nowhere near enough information.**  You'll have to explain exactly what's happening as well as show enough code to demonstrate the issue.  Where is the _rendered_ HTML for the form as seen by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `:required => true`, not `:required => "true"` on your inputs. With that corrected, you can remove all the options you are passing and just call `$("#gift-card-payment-form").validate();`.

Comment: I don't see how moving the rules from `.validate()` and into inline attributes should make any difference.  The plugin works fine both ways.